# Initialization of for with char

Tags: c++

Can we use for loop in c++ as `for(char ch : s)` ? If yes then please explain it's meaning.

Where `s` is a string passed through argument .

Comment: This notation is available since C++11. it is for-range.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-40-foreach-in-c-and-java/

Answer (score 2):

This is named [Range for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) and is a new syntax introduced in C++11.

Comment: depends what you mean for "normal for loop". think about to create an iterator and dereference it to have access to the pointed data.

Comment: Is it also valid in C?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. This is a "for each" loop. `ch` will have the value of each successive character in the string `s`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its valid in C++ and works same as 'for each' loop in Java. In this for loop we declare variables with its datatype followed by colon and name of the data structure. It is generally used for iteration over collections class.
In case of strings, it will iterate over a string.